How to customize guest account
I enabled the guest account but I want to customize the desktop and the dock with some icons and more, but all the information about the configuration that I found is related to Ubuntu, and that option is deprecated since very long time. 2015 OMG!!!
Is there any updated information to customize the guest account?
Regards,
